# Root composer.json requires package dev-develop, found package but it does not match the constraint

Tags: php, github, composer-php

I forked a GitHub repo foo/bar that I want to install using composer.

I added

```json
{
    "require": {
        foo/bar": "dev-develop"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/myuser/bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

My `bar` fork has a branch `develop`.
When I run `composer install`, I get:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires foo/bar dev-develop, found foo/bar[dev-main, v0.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been battling something very similar for awhile today. The way I got around it was by removing the "version" property in the composer.json file and creating a release in github with the version number I was targeting.

So using the example above, creating a release in github **from the develop branch** (for example: v0.1) and then requiring that in the composer.json in the application calling it might do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with gitlab. I needed to publish a composer package with the name of my feature branch. You should try that.

Comment: Can you give more details on how to do that?

Comment: I have only experience with gitlab. In the ci/cd pipeline we have a stage to publish a specific branch as a composer package. Maybe you can use this as a starting point https://docs.github.com/en/packages/quickstart#publishing-your-package

Answer (score -1):

Composer cannot find the `develop` branch.  It did find the `main` branch and tag `v0.1.0`, but no `develop`.

> found foo/bar[dev-main, v0.1.0]

Check that composer is really looking at your forked repo:

```bash
composer require -vvv "foo/bar dev-develop"
```

and look for some output that shows it looked into your fork of foo/bar.